# Online editing gettext files?

Tags: php, gettext, php-gettext

Online editing gettext files, is it possible?

I use gettext for all my PHP projects, but sides with a minor problem, want to mine user may translate my language from as Danish to Norwegian, but in this case it enste I know is that I need to export my file from Poedit there is any. other software that can export / import my files? for Poedit can I do with export as.

hope i could help me a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [SimplePo](http://code.google.com/p/simplepo/) recently, works great. You need to export the edited .po file then use command line gettext tools or POEdit to build .mo.

Comment: Tanks, all i need its this :) easy to install when i read the "readme" file ;D

Comment: I used SimplePO for a short time, but found it required too much manual intervention. I switched to using Pootle which is nice because it works with SVN (and other VCSs). I also found SimplePO didn't handle plural forms at all.

Comment: I realise this is an old question, but this [browser-based POEdit clone](http://localise.biz/free/poedit) compiles the MO files for you. It also supports plurals, context and has a POT edit mode

Answer (score 11):

This question is high on Google and the answer is a little dated. I found http://poeditor.com/ an excellent resource. It is a free website, it is very easy to get started, you can invite translators and they have a credit system where you can use automated translation tools for your strings to help you get started.

Very slick, very easy.

Comment: Good site.  I used it to translate a website.  Is pretty commercial though.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu launchpad service has a subproject "Rosetta" which provides such a tool. You could install that on your server: https://launchpad.net/rosetta

There are also:

- [Kartouche](https://developer.berlios.de/projects/kartouche)
- [Pootle](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/pootle/index)
- [TCKTranslator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcktranslator)

Comment: Hmmm how will its work, will its work from a browser or?

Comment: yes, it is a web application.

Answer (score 1):

There are also other options which were not yet mentioned:

- https://www.transifex.net/ - cloud service
- https://crowdin.com/ - cloud service
- https://weblate.org/ - free software, also available as cloud service