# Is there an gettext .po editor to run on webserver?

Tags: php, gettext

Is there a solution to generate a .po file from the source files, translate it and export the .mo file, and all that with online technologies like PHP?

At the moment, I am using poEdit, but unfortunately it doesn't support contexts, and they're really important for me.

Thanks for your repies!

Comment: Related: [PHP translation frontend similar to Rosetta?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6242478)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756141/online-editing-gettext-files) is helping somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/simplepo/

Comment: The best one I know on the internet... Thanks! But unfortunately, it doesn't allow plurals yet :(